# Typescript is compiling extremely slowly for a single file

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and am trying to follow along with a tutorial on Youtube. For some reason, running `tsc myfile.ts` takes an extremely long time to compile. I'm talking maybe 40 seconds or so. My file is very short too, it's just some simple Javascript to get us acquainted with defining types in Typescript. For the instructor, it takes a second for his file to get compiled, but I have to wait quite a while. How can I reduce the compile time?

I installed Typescript globally by running `npm install -g typescript`. My project doesn't have any `.tsconfig` files, it's literally just a `.ts` file and a basic `index.html` file.

I don't think it's relevant, but just in case, here's the .ts file I'm compiling:

```
function add(num1: number, num2: number, showResult: boolean, phrase: string) {
    const result = num1 + num2;
    if (showResult) {
        console.log(phrase + result)
    } else {
        return result
    }
}

const number1 = 5;
const number2 = 2.5
const printResult = true;
const resultPhrase = 'Result is: '

const result = add(number1, number2, printResult, resultPhrase);
```

Also, some information that is maybe useful is I'm using a Macbook Pro with an M1 chip.

Thanks!

Edit: The file DOES eventually compile, the problem is it just takes an extraordinarily long amount of time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of it is bcuz you have typescript install globally. Just because you don't have a `tsconfig.json` the it doesn't mean there isn't one your global typescript has one and it doesn't have an exclude or and a include property, there for you might be just compiling one file, but your typescript is checking all the files inside your global node_modules.

So either install typescript locally and add a tscofing to yow project or uninstall typescript globally and instead run yow code with `npx`.

To answer the question it run slow because your typescript is checking all them files at the global node_modules